# Apply conditional function based on condition of column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame where I would like to apply a simple function to every column except the first one. Take below as an example - although in reality my dataframe comprises hundreds of columns:

```
vals = [(0, 12, 0),
     (33, 0, 11),
     (44, 16, 21),
     (0, 32, 1),
     (66, 33, 27),
     (77, 0, 0)
     ]

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=list('ABC'))
```

I would like to find a way I can instigate a rule whereby each value greater than 0 is replaced with a 1. Crucially, I do not want to apply this rule to the first column, which should remain as it is.

The closest I have got is a lambda function, which isn't working at all:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0 if x.name != 'A' else x)
```

Comment: try `df.assign(**df.drop("A",1).gt(1).astype(int))` ? or `df[df.columns ^ ['A']] = df.drop("A",1).gt(1).astype(int)`

Comment: Check `df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].mask(lambda x: x.gt(0), 1)`

Comment: @anky you need `gt(0)`

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks @ShubhamSharma

Comment: or `df.iloc[:,1:] = np.heaviside(df.iloc[:,1:],0).astype(int)`; for the sample dataframe this is almost 3 times faster than the other two variants

Answer (score 0):

When using the `apply` method, the applied function will either receive all the entire column (by default and if `axis=0`), or it will receive the entire row (`axis=1`).
In your case, the lambda function is an element-wise function, this is why you need to use the `applymap` method.

```py
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B', 'C']].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> cols = ['B','C']
>>> df[cols] = df[cols].gt(0).astype(int)
>>> df
    A  B  C
0   0  1  0
1  33  0  1
2  44  1  1
3   0  1  1
4  66  1  1
5  77  0  0
```

You can change `cols` for something like `df.columns[1:]` for a more general case.